# How to invoke karate as a webapp

Tags: karate

I would like to pack karate jars as  part of a web app and invoke test using a URL in the browser or any http/restclient. How can I do that?

example : https://karate-webapp/executeIteration17.11.02.

Answer (score 0):

This was a planned feature in Karate, but is incomplete. You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-web

Maybe you can contribute !

Comment: Thanks, I will look into above suggestion and enhance it. The reason, I asked question is that we are in cloud foundry and slowly getting rid of all VMs and Physical boxes and preference is run everything as http.